# GSAP only apply scaling while mouse button is held

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have a horizontal slider with sections that scale when dragged using GSAP. The issue I have is the scaling is applied on click and the value is saved until after dragging. I need the scaling to only be applied while the mouse button is held down.
[Here](https://codepen.io/mdrei/pen/GRxMdoz) is a codepen.

```js
var drag = Draggable.create(".horizontalContainer ", {
  type: "x",
  onPress() {
    const scale = .6;
    gsap.to('.section', {scale: scale, duration: .25});
  },
  onDragEnd() {
    const xpos = this.target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    gsap.to('.section', {scale: 1, duration: .25});
    gsap.to(this.target, {x: Math.round(xpos / winWidth) * winWidth, duration: .5});
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontalContainer {
  width: 600%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 90vh;
}

.section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #deb887;
}

.section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #b8860b;
}

.section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #2f4f4f;
}

.proxy {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class='horizontalContainer'>
    <div class='section'>ScrollTrigger with Draggable</div>
    <div class='section'></div>
    <div class='section'></div>
    <div class='section'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onRelease()` callback to bring the scale back to 1.

```js
onRelease() {
  const scale = 1;
  gsap.to('.section', {scale: scale, duration: .25});
}
```

---

Code Snippet:

```js
var drag = Draggable.create(".horizontalContainer ", {
  type: "x",
  onPress() {
    const scale = .6;
    gsap.to('.section', {
      scale: scale,
      duration: .25
    });
  },
  onRelease() {
    const scale = 1;
    gsap.to('.section', {
      scale: scale,
      duration: .25
    });
  },
  onDragEnd() {
    const xpos = this.target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    const winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    gsap.to('.section', {
      scale: 1,
      duration: .25
    });
    gsap.to(this.target, {
      x: Math.round(xpos / winWidth) * winWidth,
      duration: .5
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontalContainer {
  width: 600%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 90vh;
}

.section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #deb887;
}

.section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #b8860b;
}

.section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #2f4f4f;
}

.proxy {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='horizontalContainer'>
  <div class='section'>ScrollTrigger with Draggable</div>
  <div class='section'></div>
  <div class='section'></div>
  <div class='section'></div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
```